# How to launch a photo app to view photos on phone in HTML?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, kendo-mobile

I'm developing an mobile application using Kendo Mobile. The app has a report viewer or a Kindle like reader. Our reports contain images with fine details. I want to be able to launch a photo app where the user can zoom into the image and view it in detail. As well as save and share the image with others. I want to use some great apps that already exist.

Anyone know an easy way to accomplish this? Any feedback or code snippets would be welcome?

Comment: Just open a standalone image in the browser. Users can pinch to zoom from there.

Comment: @Blazemonger, that could be very simple for you. I'm new at this, could you provide an example?

Comment: Not without seeing more of your code, no.

Comment: @Blazemonger, right now I have no code. I just have an image <img src="myimageurl" />. I have nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a "zoomable view" in kendo mobile. I haven't used this before but just found it on the kendo mobile demos section under view